# A tricky question 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are 100 employees in a company XYZ, out of that 99% are managers. How many managers should resign, so that company have only 98% managers?

Comment: Can you explain where you have difficulties with this?

Comment: When a manager resigns, does he leave the company completely, or does he stay as a non-manager employee?

Comment: @OldJohn. In which science fiction movie did you see that haappening ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have actually witnessed that happening in real life! Just wanted the question to be well-defined :)

Comment: @OldJohn. These must be very nice companies ! At my age, at least in my country, I never witnessed such situation. By the way, you were right to ask for this clarification. In fact, there are two problems in the question. You are probably the only one who identified this dual problem. Cheers.

Comment: Why a down vote to the question ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It was actually a university department where "head of department" was a managerial job with little extra money and lots of hassle :)

Comment: @Manish. You must take into account the good question raised by Old John. If the managers stay in the company as non-manager, you don't need to fire anyone. Just move one manager to another non managerial position and you have you 98% value.

Comment: @manish, if you are happy with the replies, pls select one of them as your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Today, you have hundred persons; among them 99 are managers. Let us fire X managers and not recruite anybody. Then the staff becomes (100 - X) and among them (99 - X) are managers. So, now you want that (99 - X) represent 98% of (100 - X). This gives you the equation (99 - X) = 0.98 (100 - X) the solution of which being X=50. Let us check the result : since 50 managers left, the staff is now 50 and 49 managers stay. You have your ratio.

Comment: OK, you've beaten me by 40 seconds ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe. May I suppose you are a manager to take so long time to answer ? If needed, I precise that it is a koke. Cheers.

Comment: Not at all. But I beg your pardon, as a non-native speaker I don't get the sense of your last sentence. Is there a typo in it? Thank in advance.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe. Sorry for that. I typed "koke" instead of "joke" (I am almost blind and I always hope that my typing is correct).

Answer (score 2):

Of course 50 managers: then we have 49 managers out of 50 employees that is 98 percent.